# Create Firefox 4 Style Button and Drop Down Menu on Form Title Bar C#

Tags: c#, winforms

As the title says, I am wondering if it is possible to implement a Drop Down Menu on the Title Bar of my Form, similar to Firefox 4's:

*removed dead ImageShack link*

[image: Firefox Menu Image 2]

Is it possible for me to do this with C# and WinForms? If so, how? It doesn't have to be very fancy like the Office Ribbon. In fact it can look exactly the same as the Firefox button, but with my applications name instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, no problem.  Set the form's ControlBox property to False and the Text property to an empty string.  The menu is tougher, you'll have to approximate it with a ContextMenuStrip.  Google WM_NCHITTEST to restore the window behavior that is lost because of the missing title bar.

Comment: Oh dear, it sounds a bit to complicated for my liking. I was kind of hoping that there was some kind of user control that someone had created that I could use...

Comment: @Kryten: It is usually very difficult to find UserControls for such stuff, especially when the concept is quite new as in this case. The best alternative is to work out something on your own if you really need it.